# Сортировка вложенного массива в mongose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

есть такая модель https://pastebin.com/i01Pw1Un
и есть такой запрос https://pastebin.com/06hRn2LK

можно ли как-то в этом запросе отсортировать вложенный массив words по полю created, чтобы выдача была в обратном порядке?
пробовал так: .sort({created: -1, 'words.created: -1'}) не сработало. Сортируется только только основная коллекция, а вложенный массив words остается неизменным

Comment: не совсем понятно как вы хотите отсортировать элементы по значению массивов

Comment: нужно отсортировать по полю created в обратном порядке. В поле хранится дата  в виде new Date().valueOf()

Comment: я не думаю, что можно отсортировать документы из вложенного массива без использования аггрегаций. Но из можно отсортировать уже в коде, после выборки.